# How to add cursor:pointer property to HTML email template, it's not working now

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm working on email HTML template and thing which remains to me is adding cursor:pointer property to the button.
Below is the part where I have a button:

```html
<span style="
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      ">
      <button
        type="button"
        style="
          text-align: center;
          justify-self: center;
          border: 3px solid #ea2a46;
          color: #ea2a46;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 600;
          border-radius: 10px;
          background-color: #ffffff;
          padding: 10px 15px;
          cursor: pointer !important;
        "
      >
        Activate account
      </button>
    </span>
```

I tested both for type="button" and "submit".

Although in the code we can see that property cursor:pointer is added, this property is not visible in dev tools on the  element, please check below:
[image]

Can You please suggest how to fix it ?

Comment: It looks like a few things aren't showing up, not just cursor, but also `justify-content: center;`. Something else is going on here that seems to be related to your setup, because when I put your code in a snippet, it works just fine.

Comment: Lots of bits of CSS aren’t implemented on various email systems. See canedit.com for some guidance (though it may not be totally up to date on all systems)

Comment: @AHaworth did you mean www.caniemail.com?

Comment: @Nathan yes thanks https://www.caniemail.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to use a `<button>` in an email layout at all. Because you won't be able to send the form or process any js event. Instead, use an `<a>` tag that will have a `cursor:pointer` and add the necessary styles to it.

Comment: e.g. https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-code/link-button.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate the cursor css option for gmail, though it does show up in other mail clients.  Nevertheless, gmail will change to a pointer for all a tags.  Instead of using a button, you should create a div with height/width the size of the button, as well as border and background colors that you want.  The div will define the size of the clickable area as long as you use this structure:

```
<a href="LINK" target="_blank">
      <div id="div_name">
              BUTTON TEXT
      </div>
</a>
```

You may also want to include some css inside the div to center the text like this:

```
    line-height: 48px;  //this line height is the full height of the button, to perfectly center ONE line of text
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
```